# Is it ok to slotify virtual function of base non-QObject class

Tags: c++, qt

If I declare a function virtual in the base non-QObject class and then overlaod it as a slot in the derived class that has Q_OBJECT macro and that has QObject as one of the base classes is it supposed to work ok?

Is it guaranteed that virtual calls will work? What should happen if you connenct to the slot of the derived class?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f();
};

class Derived: public QObject, public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    virtual void f();
};
```

Comment: Apparently, there seems to be some different interpretations of your question. Could you clarify it a bit, for instance by adding some sample code?

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but you should know that [`QObject` must appear first in the list of base classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first).

Comment: @LucTouraille not relevent, indeed. fixed.

Comment: I've provided some details in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes:

> Since slots are normal member functions, they follow the normal C++
>   rules when called directly. <...> You can also define slots to be virtual, which we have found quite
>   useful in practice.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#slots

In your example `Derived::f` is a normal virtual function. If it's called directly, it works as expected, just as the documentation says. When invoked by signal, it's called by `qt_static_metacall`, which is generated in `moc_Derived.cpp` as following:

```
void Derived::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, 
                                 int _id,     void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        Q_ASSERT(staticMetaObject.cast(_o));
        Derived *_t = static_cast<Derived *>(_o);
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->f(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
    Q_UNUSED(_a);
}
```

So, it ends with normal function call `_t->f()`.

Note that there is no way to invoke `Base::f` by a signal. This function can be executed only if present object is actually `Base` instance and not `Derived` instance. And since `Base` is not QObject-based, you can't pass its instance to `connect` function.

Comment: This does not really address the question.

Comment: @LucTouraille Why do you think that? I think it clearly states that slots behave as _normal_ functions (`virtual`or not). In the end, the slot invocation results in a function call, so virtuality should be correctly handled.

Comment: @JohannesS.: As I understand the question, the problem is not about virtual slots, which are explicitely allowed by the framework (as noted by Riateche), but about transforming an existing member function from a base class into a slot in a derived class (with the additional potential issue that the base class is not even a QObject).

Comment: @LucTouraille I am sorry, but I cannot get this interpretation from the question. If your interpretation is be correct, I ask the OP to edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @JohannesS. Luc Touraille's interpretation is correct and I do not see how your interpretation can be found in my question, anyway I'll add code example to be more clear.

Comment: @LucTouraille Well, I guess we were talking about the same but I might have misread/misinterpreted your answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Last edit makes it clear, am I safe in assumption that this would work in next versions of Qt too?